# GDI double buffering strangely slow

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

So I have an old-fashioned GDI app written in C. It redraws by rendering directly onto the screen, touching each pixel exactly once. Everything works fine.

I now need to upgrade it to use a more complex rendering system, where I can't guarantee that each pixel is touched once --- the rendering algorithm requires a black background. If I render directly onto the screen, however, I get flicker. So I need to double buffer.

My problem is that after adding double buffering, it's painfully slow, and I don't understand why.

In WM_SIZE, I create an off-screen surface:

```
case WM_SIZE:
{
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(window, &rect);

    HDC dc = GetDC(window);
    /* omitting freeing cachedc and cachebitmap for brevity */
    cachedc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
    cachebitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, rect.right, rect.bottom);
    SelectObject(cachedc, cachebitmap);
    ReleaseDC(window, dc);
    break;
}
```

(Note that the call to `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` uses `dc` not `cachedc`. I know about that gotcha.)

Then in WM_PAINT I do the draw:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    return 1;

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BeginPaint(window, &ps);

    FillRect(cachedc, &ps.rcPaint, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    paint_cb(window, &ps, cachedc);

    BitBlt(ps.hdc,
        ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top,
        ps.rcPaint.right, ps.rcPaint.bottom,
        cachedc,
        ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top,
        SRCCOPY);

    EndPaint(window, &ps);
    break;
}
```

That's the slow code. If, however, I change WM_PAINT to do this, then it runs quickly (although with flicker):

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BeginPaint(window, &ps);

    FillRect(ps.hdc, &ps.rcPaint, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    paint_cb(window, &ps, ps.hdc);

    EndPaint(window, &ps);
    break;
}
```

`paint_cb()` is too complex to reproduce here, but it works by blitting lots of little bitmaps onto the surface (it's rendering text, and each bitmap is a cached glyph). The bitmaps are created on demand and then cached; they get discarded in WM_SIZE. The bitmaps are created using `CreateCompatibleDC()` and `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` exactly as above.

As far as I know the code above is completely vanilla. This means that there must be some sort of assumption I'm making that's not valid. My reasoning goes:

- rendering via the off-screen bitmap is slow, therefore there must be some sort of format conversion going on during the rendering process.
- rendering directly is fast, therefore there isn't.
- therefore there must be something `paint_cb()` is doing differently depending on whether it's getting a DC to the screen or to the off-screen bitmap.
- except there isn't. `paint_cb()` neither knows nor cares.
- ???

What am I missing here? What should I be looking for? Somehow, something I'm doing in the code above is causing `paint_cb()` to slow down by about two orders of magnitude. Any suggestions as to what this might be?

Comment: What makes you think `paint_cb()` is the slow step and not the final `BitBlt` to the display?

Comment: I sure hope you've ommitted the cleanup code on purpose. You're creating GDI leaks like no-one's business above. I'm not seeing a call to `DeleteObject(cachebitmap);` or `DeleteDC(cachedc);` But in any case, what did the profiler tell you? Probably a good time to become familiar with it, if you're not already.

Comment: cachebitmap is not being selected into the cachedc.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP Cut-and-paste typo. Edited, ta.

Comment: How do you respond to WM_ERASEBACKGROUND?

Comment: @enhzflep Yes, I omitted the cleanup on purpose because the question is already too long. The real code has it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter If I just change the code to draw directly onto the screen, but don't remove the BitBlt, it redraws quickly. Therefore it can't be the BitBlt that's the limiting factor.

Comment: @DavidGiven - good, good. Great. If you'd posted a SCCCE it would have already been clear. I suggest you do just that. Failing that, upload a zip of the project somewhere. Omitting the detail necessary to answer the question in the interests of keeping it short does seem a little counter-productive.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The basic question is why code that uses hardware acceleration is faster than code that does the exact same thing *without* hwaccel *and* copies a handful of megabytes to the video adapter is slower.  The answer should be obvious.

Comment: GDI being hardware accelerated is news to me! But yeah, if the screen is accelerated and the surface being created by `CreateCompatibleContext()` isn't, then that would explain what I'm seeing. (To a certain extent --- I'm still surprised it's so slow. memcpy isn't that expensive.) Is there a way to get an accelerated off-screen surface with GDI?

Comment: How are you measuring the speeds?  One theory is that your little glyph blits are somehow going from video memory to system memory and back in the double-buffered case.  Or maybe there's color matching to do during the little blits (which seems unlikely if they're both compatible bitmaps with the same original DC).

Comment: I did a simple test and found that drawing to a compitable bitmap was more than 100 times slower than drawing to the window context. And that is just drawing to the compitable bitmap. bitblt-ing to the window context is double the time it takes to draw to the window context directly. Which is odd. Maybe something is wrong with my settings.